# How to prove the inequality by diffrential Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus

How to prove the following inequality by MVT(  Mean Value Theorem-Lagrange ):

$$y^x+x^y>1+xy,~~x,y\in(0,1).$$

Can anyone give me some suggestions about it? 
Thank you!

Comment: This ineqiality was proved already here

Comment: I can not find it,sorry!

Comment: @Graubner  Could you give me a link to the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Graubner,  Do you know how to prove it?

Comment: My name is Sonnhard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$x^y=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^y}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^y}\geq \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)y}=\frac{x}{x+y-xy}$$
Analogously we get $$y^x\geq \frac{y}{x+y-xy}$$
so we get
$$x^y+y^x>\frac{x}{x+y-xy}+\frac{y}{x+y-xy}$$
Now we have to show that $$\frac{x+y}{x+y-xy}>1+xy$$ this is true, since $$(1-x)(1-y)>0$$

Comment: @Sonnhard  Thank you very much!

Comment: I must used many sheets of paper bevor i have found this proof.

Comment: @Sonnhard   Good job!

Comment: Thank you for the flowers.